# Retrieve MySQL Events through PHP based on a date variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, date-range

Hello everyone: I am trying to get a data pull from MySQL within a PHP file that I have.  The user passes in a date (represented currently by '$selectedDate'), and I want the query to pull all events that match that date.

The problem is that the MySQL date is in a unix format, meaning it has hours, seconds, etc.  The passed in date is date only, so there won't be an exact match.

So what I am trying to do is take my date, add a variable that is minus 1 day and another one that is plus one day and pull the events in based on that range.

The problem is that it's not working and I have no idea why!  After about 2 days of trouble shooting and searching, I am relying on you my stackoverflow friends!

Any ideas?

```
  $selectedDate = '9-20-2012';
  $dateComponents = preg_split('~[+*/-]~', $selectedDate);
  $date1 = mktime(0, 0, 0, ( (int)$dateComponents[0] ), (int)$dateComponents[1]-1, (int)$dateComponents[2]);
  $date2 = mktime(0, 0, 0, ( (int)$dateComponents[0] ), (int)$dateComponents[1]+1, (int)$dateComponents[2]);

  $query = "SELECT id,title,start, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i' ) AS startDate, end, url, className FROM $tableName WHERE start BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' ORDER BY start";

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  $array = array();

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo($row);
       $array[] = $row; 

  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the Minutes and Seconds to your dates before passing them into SQL.

```
  $selectedDate = '9-20-2012';
  $dateComponents = preg_split('~[+*/-]~', $selectedDate);
  $date1 = mktime(0, 0, 0, ( (int)$dateComponents[0] ), (int)$dateComponents[1]-1, (int)$dateComponents[2]);
  $date2 = mktime(0, 0, 0, ( (int)$dateComponents[0] ), (int)$dateComponents[1]+1, (int)$dateComponents[2]);

  $date1 = date('Y-m-d h:i',$date1);
  $date2 = date('Y-m-d h:i',$date2);

  $query = "SELECT id,title,start, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i' ) AS startDate, end, url, className FROM $tableName WHERE start BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' ORDER BY start";
```

Comment: Bless you, Jeremy 1026!!!  It WOOOOOOOOOORRRRRRRRRRKKKKKKKKKKKKSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try following way

```
$start = strtotime("-1 day", strtotime('09-12-2012'));
$end = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime('09-12-2012'));

$result = my_sql_query("
          Select * FROM tablename 
          WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_field)) 
          BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME($start) AND FROM_UNIXTIME($end)");
```

Comment: Thanks GBD, but it's not working... $start ends up equal to -86391 and $end is 86409

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, title, start, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i' ) AS startDate, end, url, className 
FROM $tableName 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(start) BETWEEN '2012-09-01' - interval 1 day AND '2012-09-01' + interval 1 day 
ORDER BY start
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better of not using between whatsoever by doing something like this:

```
$selectedDate = '9-20-2012';
$dateComponents = preg_split('~[+*/-]~', $selectedDate);
$date = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $dateComponents[0], $dateComponents[1], $dateComponents[2]));

$query = "SELECT id, title, start, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS startDate, end, url, className FROM $tableName WHERE DATE(start) = DATE($date) ORDER BY start";
```

This way you would be only comparing the date part and simply ignoring the time and if you don't need to actually get a real interval and just the entries for the provided date, IMO this is a rather decent way to go.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can convert your date to unixtime before mysql query. It can help you to get date in any format.

```
$date = '9-20-2012';
$unixtime = strtotime(str_replace ('-', '/', $date). ' 00:00');
```